# Label text not change after didReceiveMemoryWarning

Tags: ios, uilabel, didreceivememorywarning

My app works great but when I simulate `didReceiveMemoryWarning` some weird things happen.
For example, in one view I have a `UILabel` and in the view Controller I change its text.
But, when I simulate `didReceiveMemoryWarning`, the text changes are not update in the view, altough from the log I see the correct value.

For example, in my `navController` I have at some point:

```
 NSLog(@"day label %@",self.dayYearController.labelData.text);
```

and the log says

```
day label 8 mer 2014
```

But in the view of `self.dayController` the labelData has not that string!
Why?
Moreover, also the `drawRect:` method of sub views of `self.dayYearController` are not called anymore after firing `didReceiveMemoryWarning` signal.

**[SOLUTION]**

I realized that in `navController` I release the subviews if I receive a didMemoryWarning signal, but when I re-create the sub view I did not add the controller as children controllers. The process of re-creation of sub view must include also the addition of their controller

Answer (score 0):

the messages will appear in the following order:

```
didReceiveMemoryWarning

viewDidUnload (which can be caused by 1) - obviously only applies to View Controller Classes.

dealloc
```

so after simulation your IBOutlet set to nil before dealloc and your view will not be able to update